# CSS video filtering with Firefox?

Tags: javascript, firefox

I use a hue-rotate, blur, contrast and brightness in Chrome, but Firefox doesn't support them.

Is there any alternative that works with `<video>`?

Comment: http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-filters

Answer (score 0):

CSS Filter Effects are not a standard yet and [only supported in Webkit](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-filters) but [there is a polyfill](https://github.com/Schepp/CSS-Filters-Polyfill) that may work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Use video + canvas. Probably a lot better support than non-standard css filter effects.

http://html5doctor.com/video-canvas-magic/